# Sorting with NA using datatable function in DT package

Tags: r, datatables, na, dt, htmlwidgets

I am trying to create an html table using the datatable function in the DT package so that when I sort the data in R markdown, missing rows are sorted after the highest number.

For example, in the following table, when I sort by "age" in the markdown file, I would like the row with NA to be listed last so that the order is 14,15,21,NA.

```
dat <- data.frame("Age" = c(21,15,NA,14), 
"Name" = c("John","Dora", "Max", "Sam"), 
"Gender" = c("M","F","M",NA))


DT::datatable(dat, filter = c("top"))
```

I have tried using "na.last = TRUE" and this works when the datatable initially prints, however when clicking the column to sort, NA is still before 14.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hi eycramer, can you explain a little bit more what you mean by "clicking the column to sort"?

Comment: @Dubukay There are some arrows at the top of each column, which serve to sort a column in descending or ascending order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `render` columnwise option, you can set the value of the missing values during the sorting:

```
library(DT)

dat <- data.frame("Age" = c(21,15,NA,14), 
                  "Name" = c("John","Dora", "Max", "Sam"), 
                  "Gender" = c("M","F","M",NA))

render <- JS(
  "function(data, type, row) {",
  "  if(type === 'sort' && data === null) {",
  "    return 999999;",
  "  }",
  "  return data;",
  "}"
)

datatable(
  dat, 
  filter = "top",
  options = list(
    columnDefs = list(
      list(targets = 1, render = render)
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This answer was very helpful

Comment: This is not working for me. I added by target column as  `columnDefs = list(
                         list(targets = 5, render = render)` but the column 5 is sorted with missing values at the top.

Comment: @LazarusThurston do you take into account column 0 ?

Comment: Yes I have taken into account starting column 0 in all my columnDefs list items. Because I hide a few columns (visible = F).